# On what day will the infection rate exceed half of the population for the first time?

Tags: sequences-and-series

This is my problem to solve:
A tenth of the population is infected. The bacterium spreads very quickly and the number of infected people increases by 6% every day. On what day will the infection rate exceed half of the population for the first time?

I use for example 100 people in population and I got on 10th day will the infection rate exceed half of the population for the first time, but this is not the right answer.

Any help?

Comment: Please edit your question to detail your attempt, so that we can detect why you didn't find $28.$

Comment: How did you get that $10$th day

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question seems to be asking on what day does the *proportion of infected people* exceed half the population. We start from $0.1$ on day $0$ (as is common in epidemiology) and multiply by $1.06$ for each succeeding day:
$$0.1(1.06)^n\ge0.5$$
We find that $n$ has to be at least [$28$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/28_Days_Later).